# slim template render title parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

i try to push some title parameters from the content section of my layout.

My content:

```
-myTitle = "title"
    == render :slim, :"_layouts/default" do #<<need to push myTitle
      //dynamic content
      section class="body" id="diashow_content" == render :html, :"_body/index"
      //<!-- Modal -->
      //-js
```

This is my default layout:

```
doctype html
    html
      head
        == render :slim, :"_head/default" #<<need to push myTitle
      body
        //invisible content
        div class="handy"
        section id="curtain" class="static" == render :html, :"_partials/curtain"
        section id="head" class="static" == render :html, :"_partials/head"
        section id="content" class="dynamic"
          == yield
        section id="loading" class="static collapse" == render :html, :"_partials/loading"
        section id="foot" class="static" == render :html, :"_partials/foot"
```

Default head where my title is:

```
meta charset="utf-8"
meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"
meta name="keywords" content="test, test2"
meta name="description" content="Ich teste nur"
meta name="robots" content="index,follow"
meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"
meta name="theme-color" content="#0E214F"
==slim :"_head/assets"

title #<< try to get myTitle attribute here
```

I hope this was transparency enough, sry for my unpleasant english skills.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define it as an instance variable so it will be available in the other templates.

`- @myTitle = "title"`